# Rails 5 API using Kaminari - how to provide the page count data to client side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I have installed Kaminari gem and have the following code in my controller:

```
  # GET /customers
  def index
    if params[:page]
      @customers = Customer.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
      pageCount = (Customer.count / params[:per_page].to_f).ceil      
    else
      @customers = Customer.order('updated_at DESC')
      pageCount = 1
    end
    render json: @customers, meta: { total: pageCount, records: Customer.count }
  end
```

This attempts to add a 'meta' section to my response with the data I need in the client to build the paging controls.

The problem is that if I make a request (eg using Postman):

localhost:3000/customers?page=1

The meta data is not added to the response.

FYI I based this off code that I used in EmberJS using JSONAPI, but now I am using Angular2, so not sure how to get this 'meta' data added to the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write like

```
render json: { customers: @customers, meta: { total: pageCount, records: Customer.count } }
```

In your example you adding just `@customers` to json response, while meta part goes somewhere else(not to response). So to have your meta section in your json response, make sure it is in correct place

Comment: `pageCount` variable and calculation is unnecessary, replace with  @customers.total_pages.  The `.total_pages` method is [provided by kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#query-basics)